# Solving systems of linear equations containing integers

Tags: systems-of-equations, integers, gaussian-elimination

If i have a system of linear equations in matrix form such as:

```
1  1  1   1 400
1 -1  0   0 0
0  1 -2   0 0
0  0  1 -10 0
```

I can solve it using gaussian elimination. However, I am curious about solving such a system if one or more of the variables is an integer. Are there techniques out there to accomplish this and what error are they attempting to reduce?

Comment: If there's one solution to the system, then that's what you get, integers or not. Are you talking about systems with dependent equations?

Comment: See [Hermite Normal Form.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form)

Comment: You mean that one or more of the solution vector is constrained to be integral? When all of them are (and you allow inequality constraints), this makes the problem NP hard.